# Как сложить все элементы массива строк?

Tags: java, android, циклы

Пишу приложение на Android Studio. Через код по нажатию кнопки добавляются дополнительные поля к посту.

В цикле получаю значения с динамически добавленных полей. Вопрос: как занести все поля в переменную, чтобы в дальнейшем её использовать?

```
String[] items = new String[allEds.size()];
//запускаем чтение всех елементов этого списка и запись в массив
for (int i = 0; i < allEds.size(); i++) {
    String strNamePers = (items[i] = ((EditText) allEds.get(i).findViewById(R.id.perona1)).getText().toString());
    String strNameVoz = (items[i] = ((EditText) allEds.get(i).findViewById(R.id.peronavoz2)).getText().toString());
    String strNameTreb = (items[i] = ((EditText) allEds.get(i).findViewById(R.id.peronatreb3)).getText().toString());
    String strNameInt = (items[i] = ((EditText) allEds.get(i).findViewById(R.id.peronasumm4)).getText().toString());
    String hr="<hr>";
    String br = "<br>";
    fnlstr = (br +"название персонажа: " + strNamePers + br+"возраст: "+strNameVoz+br+"требования к типажу: "+strNameTreb+br+"Сумма оплаты"+strNameInt+br+hr);
    Log.d("mylog", "масив с полей " + fnlstr);
}
```

Проблема в том, что в переменной `fnlstr` хранится значение только последней итерации цикла. Как сделать, чтобы все итерации сложились в одну строку и занеслись в переменную `fnlstr`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если нужно соединить (конкатенировать) все полученные строки в одну, то делается это через оператор `+` (`+=`):

```
fnlstr += (br +"название персонажа: " + strNamePers + br+"возраст: "+strNameVoz+br+"требования к типажу: "+strNameTreb+br+"Сумма оплаты"+strNameInt+br+hr);
```

Если до цикла `fnlstr` не инициализирована, то нужно это сделать.

```
fnlstr = "";
for...
```

К сожалению, конкатенация строк в цикле подобным образом неэффективна, т.к. на каждой итерации создается новая, более длинная строка. Поэтому когда нужно сложить строки в цикле используется [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

```
StringBuilder fnlstrBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < allEds.size(); i++) {
    //пропущен не имеющий отношения к делу код
    fnlstrBuilder.append(br +"название персонажа: " + strNamePers + br+"возраст: "+strNameVoz+br+"требования к типажу: "+strNameTreb+br+"Сумма оплаты"+strNameInt+br+hr);
}
```

После цикла можно получить строку с помощью `toString`:

```
fnlstr = fnlstrBuilder.toString();
```

Comment: приложение падает с ошибкой  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.StringBuilder java.lang.StringBuilder.append(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: а вот первый вариант fnlstr += (br +"название персонажа: " + strNamePers + br+"возраст: "+strNameVoz+br+"требования к типажу: "+strNameTreb+br+"Сумма оплаты"+strNameInt+br+hr); Отлично сложил все итерации .... Спасибо)

Comment: @dimasta68 Пожалуйста, если что ошибка говорит о том, что Вы не создали `StringBuilder`. Проверьте, что в коде есть `= new StringBuilder();` и что он присвоен правильной переменной.